# Does the datatable currency formatter support localisation in YUI2(.9)

Tags: datatable, alfresco-share, currency-formatting, yui2

When attempting to save a information from a datatable in share, I have a problem with the french locale for numbers that are in view in that when I save, the numbers are saved as displayed in view (i.e. commas instead of periods to denote the decimal places).

```
parent.widgets.pagingDataTable = new Alfresco.util.DataTable({
                            dataTable: {
                                container: parent.id + "-datatable",
                                columnDefinitions: columnDefinitions,
                                config: {
                                    MSG_EMPTY: parent._msg("message.noProducts"),
                                    responseType: YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSON,
                                    responseSchema: {
                                        resultsList: "productList",
                                        fields: ["photo", "unitQuantity", "minQuantity", "unitPrice", "descriptionProduct"],
                                    },
                                    currencyOptions: {suffix: '€', decimalPlaces: 2, decimalSeparator: ',', thousandsSeparator: '.'},
                                }
                            }
```

Has anyone had this issue with currency formatter and localization in YUI 2.

Comment: What issue? What is the result at the moment.

Comment: @TahirMalik Apologies I didn't realise the preceeding text was missing.